# How to get URL params when using Custom Document in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization

I am using NextJS to product SSR pages, and these pages are language-specific. I would like to set the lang property to declare the language of the text.

So far I have:

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"
import Router from "next/router"

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    const { lanaguage } = Router.router.query
    return (
      <Html lang={language}>
        <Head />
        <body className="antialiased text-white text-base font-sans">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

However, `Router.router` is always `null` when using a Custom Document (`_document.js`). Is there another way to get the URL params/query when using a Custom Document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Next.js v10, if you're using the built-in [i18n routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing), Next will automatically set the `lang` attribute of the document.

From the documentation:

> Since Next.js knows what language the user is visiting it will
> automatically add the `lang` attribute to the `<html>` tag.
>
> Next.js doesn't know about variants of a page so it's up to you to add
> the `hreflang` meta tags using `next/head`. You can learn more about
> `hreflang` in the [Google Webmasters documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?visit_id=637543390382043375-2619640130&rd=1).

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to solve this by using:

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    const { lanaguage } = this.props.__NEXT_DATA__.query
    return (
      <Html lang={lanaguage}>
        <Head />
        <body className="antialiased text-white text-base font-sans">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

I am unsure if it is bad practice to use `this.props.__NEXT_DATA__`. However, it does have the information I require.